# What is the status of the LaTeX3 Project?

Tags: latex3

I was just downloading a new copy of LaTeX for my Mac and I noticed this comment on the www.latex-project.org website:

## The LaTeX3 Project

### LaTeX3 Project

*The LaTeX3 project is a long-term research project to develop the next version of the LaTeX typesetting system.*

So I looked at [the link](https://www.latex-project.org/latex3/) and it refers to the [1999 article by Mittelbach and Rowley describing the LaTeX3 Project](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ltx3info.pdf).

So it's been 20 years since the Mittlebach and Rowley article came out. That's certainly long-term. Did LaTeX3 ever happen?

Comment: the latex3 project maintain latex, so it is still very active.  most of the latex3 code is available in the expl3 package callable from latex2e and used in fontspec, unicode-math siunitx and serveral other popular packages.

Comment: I get the feeling that we have this question every week.

Comment: The status of the LaTeX project can be tracked on https://github.com/latex3/latex3

Comment: @DavidCarlisle given that the related question is now ~9 years old, it seems fair to ask again.

Comment: @Martin and presumably fair to give same answer?

Comment: @Martin The site model doesn't really work that way.  It can be tricky when the answer changes significantly, but here the older question is still valid. So I'm afraid this one looks like a dupe to me.